# C++/MFC How do I make from 15346: 15000,300,40,6?

Tags: c, mfc, int

I need a part number for tens of hundreds of thousands of units, etc.

```
int a1;
int a2;
int a3;
int a4;

int a = 15346;

a = ?
```

Comment: mod/div/mod/div/mod/div.......

Comment: Any why do you tag a C++ question C, not C++? Read [ask] and take the [tour] once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the modulus (`%`) operator to get the last digit, then subtract that value and repeat. For example

```
int value = 15436
int ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, tenthousands;
ones = value % 10 // gives 6
value = value - ones  // leaves 15340
tens = value % 100 // gives 40
value = value - tens  // leaves 15300
hundreds = value % 1000 // gives 300
value = value - hundreds // leaves 15000
thousands = value % 10000 // gives 5000
value = value = thousands // leaves 10000
tenthousands = value % 100000 // gives 10000
```

etc. This is an extremely naive example, you'd probably want to do this in a loop and with arrays, but the concept is the same.
I guess a better way to do it is modulus and division instead of modulus and subtraction

```
int val = 15346
int place = val % 10 // gives 6
val = val / 10 // leaves 1534
place = val % 10 // gives 4
```

so

```
int val = 15346;
int place[5];
int indx = 0;
while(val > 10 && idx < 5) {
  place[idx--] = val % 10;
  val = val / 10;
}
```